# What is causing this error while connecting Android Studio App to Mysql with Jdbc

Tags: android, jdbc, mysql-connector

When attempting to use this query to save data to a mysql local database using this code:

```
private void addEvent_query(String eventEndDateTime, String eventFrequencyText, String eventIdText, String isGoal, String eventNameText, String eventNotificationDateTime, String eventStartDateTime) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.out.println("Driver not loaded");
        return;
    }

    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost", "root", "GroupG");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into DBO.EVENT(EndDate, Frequency, Id, IsGoal, Name, NotificationDate, StartDate) " +
                "values (" + eventEndDateTime + ", " + eventFrequencyText + ", " + eventIdText + ", '" + isGoal + "', '" + eventNameText + "', '" + eventNotificationDateTime + "', '" + eventStartDateTime + "')");

        conn.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        return;
    }
}
```

I get the following error when trying to invoke it:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Invalid descriptor: CapabilitiesGetOrBuilder.
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:58) 
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378) 
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.(NonRegisteringDriver.java:99) 
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378) 
>           at com.example.earlybird.AddEventActivity.addEvent_query(AddEventActivity.java:251) 
>           at com.example.earlybird.AddEventActivity.access$900(AddEventActivity.java:24) 
>           at com.example.earlybird.AddEventActivity$8.onClick(AddEventActivity.java:240)

Comment: `to a mysql local database` are you sure it is as much local as you expect? Does it run on the same Android device you are executing this app?

Comment: Also on which line do you get that exception?

Comment: You shouldn't use JDBC drivers from Android. Use a rest API to mediate between your application and the database. In this case the error is probably related to a recent Java feature being used which is not supported by Android.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko it is running from MySQL on my local machine, but not on the android device itself. The line that is causing the issue seems to be to be: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I was hoping to avoid using a rest API, but may have to look into it.

Comment: `jdbc:mysql://localhost` will connect to the same device as you call from, therefore - to your Android device.

Comment: I was able to fix the crash by re-implementing the connector as a java module and adding dependency on the app instead of having the .jar in the lib folder. It removed the crash, but data still isn't being written to the database. I also changed the getConnection source to: jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2/dbo